# iphone video streaming

Tags: iphone, video, stream

So, I recently submitted my first iphone app to Apple.
I did not stream my videos and they are over 10 minutes long, so my app was denied because I did not use HTTP Live Streaming.

So, we stream live videos every week. Those files are stored somewhere, but I am a little unsure of where. I want the video files that I made a feed for to be converted into streamed videos. But I don't want to use Apple's HTTP Live software. I do not know how to code into streamed video.

Is there anyway to either figure out where my streamed files are storing or is there a software that will convert videos into streamed video? Will take any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you must use HTTP Live Streaming if you wan't your app to be approved, and also be aware of the Apple restrictions (you must set different bitrates, one of 64kbps or lower).

If you don't want to use Apple tools, you can use ffmpeg. Take a look at ioncannon.net http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

With Apple tools is easier. You just need mediafilesegmenter/mediastreamsegmenter.

There is also professional services out there, but not free, that will take care of all the process.

If you don't know where are your files, maybe you can use a sniffer and check where is your computer "listening to".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to simply require that your users be on WiFi in order to watch the videos. The 10 min. / 5MB restriction only applies to video that is sent over Cellular networks, not WiFi. See Apple's "Reachability" code for an example of how to test the user's network connection at run-time.